# Bootstrap Nav-link - change font color based on scrolling

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

This is my first post and I appreciate if you could help me with this issue.
I have read several posts but did not find the solution so far.

I am using the navbar component from Bootstap (v5.0).
I would like to change the navbar and nav-link color when the user scrolldown.

So far I have been successfull with changing the color of the navbar but not of the nav-link(s).
I have attached the snippet to the post.

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

```js
var navBar = document.getElementById('navbar')
var textNavBars = document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-link');

window.onscroll = function () {
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 200) {
        navBar.classList.add('nav-colored');
        navBar.classList.remove('nav-transparent');
        for (const textNavBar of textNavBars) {
            textNavBar.classList.add('text-transparent')
            textNavBar.classList.add('text-colored')
        }
    } else {
        navBar.classList.add('nav-tranparent');
        navBar.classList.remove('nav-colored');
        for (const textNavBar of textNavBars) {
            textNavBar.classList.add('text-colored')
            textNavBar.classList.add('text-transparent')
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-colored { 
    background-color:#FF7F2F; 
    transition: background-color 3s
}
.nav-transparent{ 
    background-color:transparent;
    transition: background-color 3s;
}

.text-transparent{
    color: black;
}
.text-colored{
    color: #FF7F2F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spike - NavBar fotter and overall design</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#"> TEST</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle .text-colored" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
        <p style="padding-top: 5rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut deleniti odit error ratione inventore, temporibus corporis numquam odio minus a illum quis accusantium dignissimos, fuga libero velit labore, nemo adipisci.
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident hic doloremque id deleniti dolore impedit, nesciunt odio corporis itaque blanditiis sunt reiciendis cumque debitis necessitatibus adipisci ipsum optio omnis? Non.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, suscipit possimus illum eius voluptate dolorum et fugit quod rerum, minus laboriosam consequuntur quibusdam, iusto eligendi odit animi earum sapiente mollitia.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore repellat ex incidunt nesciunt, debitis voluptates rerum inventore voluptas quos provident architecto repudiandae voluptatem qui repellendus, porro nulla esse sit tempore?
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, sit. Sit quae, in, cum repellat vero nesciunt, commodi qui aliquam minima quos odit voluptates inventore sequi sed hic consectetur asperiores!
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugit mollitia, possimus veniam sunt error laudantium obcaecati repellendus, aperiam similique aliquam est vel et quasi. Iure pariatur eligendi ratione doloremque.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam laborum iure unde beatae ullam voluptatem distinctio fuga enim at tempora veniam ipsam minima tenetur natus, consectetur eos modi laudantium ratione?
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo maiores quod cupiditate sapiente culpa aspernatur obcaecati, sequi vero quisquam nobis inventore est vitae eligendi debitis incidunt. Repellat quod est aliquid?
        </p>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your styles for `.text-colored` are being overridden by this Bootstrap's style:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.55);
}
```

As the style above is using three classes to select the links, its selector is more specific, so that it will be applied instead of this, which uses only one class:

```
.text-colored {
    color: #FF7F2F;
}
```

To know more about CSS specificity and how it's calculated, see [Specificity - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

The solution to your problem would be simply adding the `!important` rule to your style declaration:

```
.text-colored {
    color: #FF7F2F !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno, really appreciate your quick feedback and your support!